# DynamoDB contain() FilterExpression with query() instead of scan()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to fetch all items with query() from table not with scan as it is very expensive
Can I use .contains() without table.scan()

```py
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table= dynamodb.Table('investors')
data = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('groups_name').contains('person_name')
)

# Something like this
data = table.query(...
    ....    
    ('groups_name').contains('person_name')
)
```

In my DynamoDB -> investors (Table)*(all have same partition key='fund')*
        -> sample item -> groups_name [list]: person_name (String)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fetch all items from a table and have more than one partition key value, you will have to use `Scan`. The `Query` API operates on a single item collection (i.e. all items with the same partition key) and filtering using the `FilterExpression` can also be done there.

A contains filter isn't available for a `KeyConditionExpression` or the `FilterExpression` in the Query operation as well, the closest match would be `starts_with`, but that's different.

To handle this access pattern efficiently, you need to reconsider your data model.

Comment: Yes I have all items with the same partition key (assume partition key name='fund'). How to query with FilterExpression?

Comment: As I tried to express: `contains` is **not** available in a `FilterExpression` of `Query`. You need to use `Scan` for that. Besides FilterExpressions are evaluated after the read, it wouldn't save you and Money except for bandwitdh